# C# Interface casting... dictionary lookup?

Tags: c#

Does C# do a dictionary lookup every time you cast an Object to an interface?  I'd think it'd have to.

Generic object that could implement hundreds of interfaces -> GetType() -> Get interface by name (or numeric ID, not going to be in a predictable location) -> Get method pointers from array and save to the casted object

Comment: ?? Why would it work that way ??

Comment: lol sorry, i didnt see the other comments!  I just don't see any other way it would work...

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we have:

```
object x = whatever;
IFoo y = (IFoo)x;
```

You are correct in noting that there must be some way in which the runtime, not the compiler, determines whether that succeeds or throws an invalid cast exception.

The exact details of how the runtime does so are an implementation detail, and it is *complicated*. The runtime uses a number of fairly sophisticated techniques to ensure that this test is fast in common cases. Moreover, an interesting characteristic of the CLR is that referential identity and value identity are the same thing; if the type test succeeds then the bits stored in x and y are the same. (This is not typically the case in C++; rather, different "views" of the object result in different pointers.) This means that additional mechanisms have to be implemented in order to efficiently handle the dispatch of interface methods.

I do not have sufficient knowledge or expertise on CLR internals to describe to you precisely how all these mechanisms work. Perhaps you could ask a more specific question if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with the runtime at all.. it's all handled during compile phase.

Comment: The question is about the scenario "object x = whatever; IFoo y = (IFoo)x;" The compiler has no idea if x actually implements IFoo or not, but it might, so the compiler defers that to runtime.

Comment: @PinnyM: OK I will. But I'm not sure why you think that doesn't seem right. Is there some technique for determining if an object implements an interface that doesn't involve looking up that fact somewhere? Where would that information come from?

Comment: @EricLippert: It could be looked up using a known memory location (managed and built as assemblies load) rather than a dictionary hash or list iteration. I had presumed that types did have a concrete definition that could be directly referenced by objects at runtime. Is this not the case?

Comment: If you have the type info, how do you get interface methods which could be at any location relative to your type?  You have to iterate the interfaces on the type info to find the right one.  I bet 99% of programmers don't know this.  I HOPE C# saves the method locations to the cast so it's only an expensive operation on cast, not every time you use it.

Comment: Can't really get a concrete answer on performance, C# is optimizing my profiling app even though I don't have optimizing turned on